# Como definir um favicon? É obrigatório defini-lo?

Tags: html, html-tags, favicon

Existem certas coisas que, por não fazer constantemente, sempre acabo esquecendo como se faz. E uma delas é a definição de um `favicon` para meu site.

Qual é a tag e os atributos que devo usar para definição correta de um favicon no meu site? (eu sempre esqueço, mas agora não vou esquecer mais :p)

Outra dúvida que eu gostaria de tirar é:

- Por que, mesmo não definindo um `favicon`, sempre recebo um erro 404?

Exemplo (com servidor built-in do PHP, mas também acontece com outras linguagens e bibliotecas):

[image: Favicon retornando erro 404]

Afinal de contas:

- o uso `favicon` é opcional ou não?
- Ele sempre precisar ter aquele caminho `/favicon.ico`?

Comment: No caso de como defini-lo, talvez tenha errado mesmo por conta da parte do opcional, desculpe, removido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `favicon` é definido por um elemento de relação (`<link rel>`) no cabeçalho de sua página, dentro do elemento `<header>`.

Enquanto que a presença de um `favicon` é opcional, seu browser sempre tentará realizar o download de um arquivo da definição padrão - `{root}/favicon.ico`.

Os tipos MIME `image/png`, `image/gif` ou `image/ico` são suportados por todos os browsers modernos.  Em alguns browsers, GIFs animados terão apenas o primeiro frame utilizado (IE e Safari, à época desta resposta.)

Suporte a outros formatos está disponível, porém a implementação não é consistente.

O caminho para sua imagem pode ser definido na propriedade `href`.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" />
```

[Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

Comment: Cara, valeu. +1, mas fica só entre gatos

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tá valendo, depois te passo o pote de Whiskas.

Comment: [Alguém disse Whiskas?](https://goo.gl/stTPmy)